# Mathematica: dynamic number of menus

Tags: dynamic, menu, wolfram-mathematica, plot

I am trying to make a dynamic number of drop-down menus in a plot, to plot a various number of curves.
I have [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487586) requested help to plot this data, and it worked well.

First thing

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
```

Here is a example of **data** (not actual numbers, as they are waaay too long).

```
data={{year, H, He, Li, C, O, Si, S},
{0, .5, .1, .01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001},
{100, .45, .1, .01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001},
{200, .40, .1, .01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001},
{300, .35, .1, .01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001}}
```

The **compounds** variable is the number of compounds+1

```
compounds=8
```

For now, my code is this one

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogLogPlot[
  {data[[All, {1, i}]],
   data[[All, {1, j}]],
   data[[All, {1, k}]]},
   PlotLegend -> {data[[1, i]],
                 data[[1, j]],
                 data[[1, k]]}
 ],
 {{i, 2, "Compound 1"},Thread[Range[2, compounds] -> Drop[data[[1]], 1]]},
 {{j, 3, "Compound 2"},Thread[Range[2, compounds] -> Drop[data[[1]], 1]]},
 {{k, 4, "Compound 2"},Thread[Range[2, compounds] -> Drop[data[[1]], 1]]},
 ContinuousAction -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, I can easily add a compound by duplicating each of the 3 lines (data, legend and menu descriptor), but it's lame and inefficient. Plotting a set takes about 20 seconds, so it's about 1 minute here (and I use a pretty efficient cluster).

Is there a solution to add a little menu or field where I can add the number of compounds to plot, so the right number of menus will display? I don't need more than 7 plots, but efficiency...

The numbers **2, 4, 16** are the default values to plot. I can make a list with the default values (2, 14, 16, and some others I may pick), or they could all be set to 2.

Thanks

Comment: Your code does not run, it is not complete. What is 'data' ? Better to post a small complete example that actually run.

Comment: I added a portion of data I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogLogPlot[data[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ i],
 {{n, 3, "# compounds"}, Range[7], 
  Dynamic[If[Length[i] != n, i = PadRight[{2, 4, 16}, n, 2]];
   PopupMenu[#, Range[7]]] &},
 {{i, {2, 4, 16}}, ControlType -> None},
 Dynamic[Column[
   Labeled[PopupMenu[Dynamic[i[[#]]], 
       Thread[Range[2, compounds] -> Drop[data[[1]], 1]]],
      Row[{"Compound ", #}], Left] & /@ Range[n]]
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without `PlotLegend`, this runs quite fast for a random data set of about 1000x1000 elements. If I include the `PlotLegend` option in `ListLogLogPlot`, it slows down quite a lot so that might be the reason why your code was so slow.

Comment: This works perfectly, and fast. I am not familiar with that kind of plotting and the incorrect placement of the legend function was slowing down everything. Thanks.

Comment: There's a bug in this code (at least when you try to get this to work with the supplied data). The numbers 16 should be replaced with a number not larger than the number of compounds. Range[7] may be replaced by Range[compounds-1]

Comment: Changing to i = PadRight[i, n, 2] allows you to keep the existing choices -- those that still remain -- as you alter the value of n.

Comment: I'm using this code as it works great. However, is there a way to identify the curve, such as coloring the button, the text in front of the button, or draw a legend?

Comment: Nervermind, I did find a solution, adding     PlotLegend->[data[[1,i]]]

Comment: @Sjoerd: The OP mentioned that he/she didn't need more than 7 plots which is why I used Range[7]. I guess the initial indices `{2, 4, 16}` could be replaced with `Max[compounds, #]& /@ {2,4,16}` to account for data arrays with less than 16 compounds.

Comment: @Billouman: If you want to colour the text in front of the buttons with the corresponding colours in the plot, you could replace `Row[{"Compound ", #}]` with something like `Style[Row[{"Compound ", #}], ColorData[1][#]]` (assuming that you're using the standard colours in `ListLogLogPlot`).

Answer (score 4):

How about something like:

```
Manipulate[
 Manipulate[ ListLogLogPlot[Table[Subscript[x, n], {n, 1, numCompounds}]],
  Evaluate@Apply[Sequence,Table[{{Subscript[x, n], n + 1, "Compound " <> ToString@n}, 
  Thread[Range[2, compounds] -> Drop[data[[1]], 1]]}, {n, 1, 
  numCompounds}]], ContinuousAction -> False],
 {{numCompounds, 3}, 1, compounds - 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add a DM version. If you're like me you may find that easier than using manipulate. It is essentially a DM version of Heike's answer.

```
DynamicModule[{data,compounds,n=1,c={2},labels},

  data=yourData;

  compounds=Length[data[[1]]];
  labels=Rule@@@Transpose[{Range[7],data[[1,2;;]]}];

  Column[{
    Dynamic[
      Grid[
        Join[
          {{"no. of compounds",PopupMenu[Dynamic[n],Range[7]]}},
          Table[
            With[{i=i},
              c=PadRight[c,n,2];
              {"compound"<>ToString[i], PopupMenu[Dynamic[c[[i]]],labels]}
            ],
            {i,n}
          ]
        ],
        Alignment->{{Right,Left},Center}
      ],
      TrackedSymbols:>{n}
    ], 
    Dynamic@ListLogLogPlot[data[[All,{1,#}]]&/@c]  
  }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've used Grid because it allows you to easily keep all the controllers and their labels aligned. `PadRight[c,n,2]` allows you to keep current settings if you change the value of n. I'd avoid plot legends and always make your own.